# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected Code 800A13F

Tags: node.js

I just started to learn and train about node js. I was already installing node js version 2.14.7 64bit. Then. I was writing a code to make basic server.

```
var sys = require("sys"), 
my_http = require("http");
my_http.createServer(function(request,response){
response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8090);
sys.puts("Server Running on 8090");
```

Then I was running the page from cmd. But I get error

```
Script : D:\node.js\test4.js
line : 1
char : 1
Error : Object Expected
Code : 800A138F
Source : Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are double-clicking on the file, which by default will execute the file with Microsoft's JScript implementation. To execute the file under node.js, you will have to start your script at the command line with something like `node test4.js` (assuming you are in `D:\node.js`).

Comment: Thanks. I am just beginner. I try it, then I got another error. Cannot find module :D\test4.js

Comment: When you open the command prompt you have to make sure you are in the correct directory. At a new command prompt, type `D:`, then `cd D:\node.js`, and then `node test4.js`.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your node.js file inside the "users" folder , then you can get this kind of errors.

The best way to solve this is that you make a folder inside the D:\ like "D:\node" and then with the help of "cd" or "cd.." command in you cmd to navigate to the folder and run "node test4.js".

Hope it solves your problem.