# npm start Microsoft JScript runtime error 800A138F object expected

Tags: node.js, windows-7, npm

Getting started with NPM...

I can run the following command to start my app.

```
node app
```

But when I run the following command, I get the following error:

```
npm start
```

> Windows Script Host
>   Object expected
>
> Line 2
>
> 800A138F
>
> Microsoft JScript runtime error

App.js:

```
var port = 5000;
var express = require('express');
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3"
  }
}
```

And I've run this command of course:

```
npm install express --save
```

Seems like NPM can't find the express package? Why not?

Comment: getting the same error, already 8 months to this question, may I know if you can recall, how you resolved this?

______________________
Edit : Resolved!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know its too late to answer, but in case any wanderer like me faces the same problem in future..

### Solution:

need to add `node` keyword ahead of `app.js` in script.  So, start script should

`"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },`

That solved for me.

Comment: dude i've been developing for 3 years .. even i forgot to add this.. thank you ! lol

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well. The .js files are associated with the Microsoft Script Engine. Some suggested that we dis-associate the extension with the program, but I do not think that is necessary. I was able to fix the issue with the following instruction that I found in the NODE Docs.

Please make sure that your file(s) referenced in bin starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

otherwise the scripts are started without the node executable!

Answer (score 1):

Use >node app.js instead of >app.js

Then it will work

Answer (score 1):

When I faced the same problem using Visual Studio Code, I was trying to run localhost at port 8080, however by pressing F5 I was able to know that the port was already taken and so I changed the port to 3000, and viola! that worked for me.

[image: Check out the error]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio Code, it may have taken over running the script. If in VS Code, hit F5 and see if the project runs properly. 
I don't know why it does this, but did for me. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327433/1298523) tipped me off