# Getting this error while installing react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting this error while trying to install react js . After typing npm start this error comes how to resolve this error

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run your React project by double-clicking the app.js file? That won't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm start Microsoft JScript runtime error 800A138F object expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535253/npm-start-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-800a138f-object-expected)

Comment: Check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936885/npm-run-script-causes-windows-script-host-error

Comment: If you find this difficult. Then you can watch a video on youtube about how to create react project in windows.