# Virtualenv won't create environment; runtime error

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a simple `virtualenv` environment; `python` and `virtualenv` are both installed. When I go in to my directory in which I am trying to make this environment, I keep getting a Windows Script Host popup box:

```
Script: *My path to virtualenv.js*
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Object expected
Code: 800A138F
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

I went in to my file to see where the problem may have lied and assumed it was just a module I hadn't installed yet, though all of them are in the `node_modules` in my package. I'm not sure where else this issue is coming from?

Comment: Can you share with us the code/steps that you are using to create your `virtualenv`? Also, I don't know much about it, but would [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327355/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-expected-code-800a13f#34327433) be related? Are you double-clicking on that file to get this error?

Comment: Hey @ArthurSpoon, my virtualenv.js file is accessed and automatically created in my directory -> node_modules\virtualenv\lib. 

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var childProcess = require("child_process");
var crypto = require("crypto");
var tar = require("tar");
var zlib = require("zlib");
var glob = require("glob");
var rimraf = require("rimraf");
var request = require("request");
var semver = require("semver");
var pypi = require("./pypi");

var VERSION = require("../package.json").version;

is the beginning of it. I'll look in to that real quick...

Comment: @ArthurSpoon I was trying to run this through terminal also

Comment: Are you trying to use a normal Python `virtualenv`, or are you using the `node-virtualenv` node.js project?

Comment: @MykWillis I was trying to do this in terminal through a normal Python virtualenv, by typing 'virtualenv venv'. For reference, I'm replicating this: http://clouddatafacts.com/heroku-connect/flask_psycopg2/flask_psycopg2_prebuilt_get.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me as if you have a `virtualenv.js` JavaScript file on your path, and that JS files are associated with Windows Scripting Host on your machine. (Perhaps you have the `node-virtualenv` project installed, which puts a JavaScript file with the name `virtualenv.js` in your path?)

To create a typical Python virtual environment, you want to invoke the (Python) virtualenv.py script. Assuming you've installed virtual environment with:

> pip install virtualenv

Then you can use:

> python -m virtualenv ENV

to invoke the Python interpreter directly, and have it load the appropriate virtualenv.py script file on your path.